# Add a new date row for every day where greater than a date column and less than another date column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, dateadd

I am trying to add in SQL Server table a new row for every day between two columns, start and end date columns.

Here is a sample table. Add a new row for every day between order and shipping dates, including the start and end dates.

| Name | Date of Birth | Order Date | Shipping Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | 02-24-2001 | 01-12-2021 | 01-15-2021 |
| M Jackson | 12-16-1992 | 03-17-2021 | 03-20-2021 |

My ideal output table to be like this.

| Name | Date of Birth | Order Date | Shipping Date | Dates Range |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | 02-24-2001 | 01-12-2021 | 01-15-2021 | 01-12-2021 |
| John Smith | 02-24-2001 | 01-12-2021 | 01-15-2021 | 01-13-2021 |
| John Smith | 02-24-2001 | 01-12-2021 | 01-15-2021 | 01-14-2021 |
| John Smith | 02-24-2001 | 01-12-2021 | 01-15-2021 | 01-15-2021 |
| M Jackson | 12-16-1992 | 03-17-2021 | 03-20-2021 | 03-17-2021 |
| M Jackson | 12-16-1992 | 03-17-2021 | 03-20-2021 | 03-18-2021 |
| M Jackson | 12-16-1992 | 03-17-2021 | 03-20-2021 | 03-19-2021 |
| M Jackson | 12-16-1992 | 03-17-2021 | 03-20-2021 | 03-20-2021 |

Note that I have hundreds of rows to duplicate, and date range can be months in some cases, so can not code one by one, looking for a sequence query that can do this for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select Name, Date_of_Birth, Order_Date, Shipping_Date, Order_Date as date_range
      from t
      union all
      select Name, Date_of_Birth, Order_Date, Shipping_Date, 
             dateadd(day, 1, date_range)
      from cte
      where date_range < coalesce(shipping_date, convert(date, getdate()))
     )
select *
from cte
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Comment: Thanks! what if I have a NULL in the shipping date which I do in some cases? I need to have it keep adding days rows until the current date, is that possible?

Comment: @TaifAlshakir . . . You should be clear about such things in your question.  I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated to trap NULL shipping dates**

Just another option is via an ad-hoc tally/numbers table.  Note I set days to 5,000.  You can adjust to any reasonable amount

**Example**

```
Select A.*
      ,[Date Range] = dateadd(DAY,N,A.[Order Date])
 From  YourTable A
 Join (
        Select Top 5000 N=-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) 
         From  master..spt_values n1 ,master..spt_values n2 
      ) B on N<=datediff(DAY,A.[Order Date],coalesce(A.[Shipping Date],getdate()))
 Order By [Date Range] -- optional
```

**Results**

I added a NULL shipping date record

[image]